# How to link accounts in AWS

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-sdk

I have tried multiple scenarios to login a user through AWS with email/password, Facebook, and Google. I can't seem to figure out how to link the separate accounts to one user. From what I'm understanding, I need to use an Identity Pool.

1) Using amazon-cognito-auth-js

- Easy to implement, but doesn't use an Identity Pool, and so I have no idea how to merge the accounts.

2) Using Amazon-Cognito-identity-js with aws-sdk

- Slightly more complicated, but allows me to add users to the Identity Pool. However, accounts aren't linking. I think I might need to do something with IAM roles.

I think I may not quite understand fully how Identity Pools work with Third Party sign-ins, and about IAM roles. I'm not looking for code answers, but just some guidance on how something like this would work. The AWS docs are so incredibly hard to do follow.

Comment: Have you tried AWS organisation ? you can link multiple AWS account under single account.

Comment: That’s not quite what I’m going for. We just need to be able to identify a user in our application as the same user regardless of whether they sign in with Facebook, Google, or their email